# Test if function has a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jestjs

I'm using jest.js and I am testing a function to see if it requires a parameter of a date object. Is there a way to test for this.

Example:

```
export function setEndDate(date){
  // do something with the date object passed in. 
}
```

In my test.js

```
test('setEndDate method should have a date object param', ()=>{
    // test that the method will allow only one parameter 
    // if possible test that it excepts param of type date object
});
```

Comment: How is your method going to error if more than one element, or a non date, is passed?

Comment: Parameters are not restricted by type in JavaScript. And any function can always accept any number of parameters regardless of the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rest parameter or `arguments` and check the function has only one argument passed and that argument is equal to `Date` when `instanceof` is used to evaluate the argument

```js
function setDate(...args) {
  let date = args[0];
  let len = args.length === 1;
  return !!(date && len && date instanceof Date);
}

console.log(setDate()); // false
console.log(setDate(new Date())); // true
console.log(setDate(new Date(), 123)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions will take in any number of arguments that you (don't) give them.  Also they can be of any type.  If you want to force restrictions you'd have to write that logic yourself.  Possibly something like the following.

```js
function setEndDate(date){
  if (Object.keys(arguments).length != 1) throw new Error("Argument count incorrect");
  if (!(date instanceof Date)) throw new Error("date must be a Date");
  
  console.log("It's all good!");
}

try { setEndDate() } catch ( e ) { console.log( e.message ); }
try { setEndDate(7, 5) } catch ( e ) { console.log( e.message ); }
try { setEndDate(7) } catch ( e ) { console.log( e.message ); }
try { setEndDate(new Date()) } catch ( e ) { console.log( e.message ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assert that the method throws an error when given non-Date arguments, or when passed two arguments (not sure why you would want to force it to Throw when passed more than one argument exactly).

```
test('setEndDate method should have a date object param', ()=>{
    expect(setEndDate({})).toThrow();
    expect(setEndDate(null)).toThrow();
    expect(setEndDate(1)).toThrow();
    expect(setEndDate('asdf')).toThrow();
    expect(setEndDate(new Date(), new Date())).toThrow();
});
```